# Сервис для проверки местоположения не работает на android 10.0 и новее

Tags: java, android, gps

Есть служба, она запускается при входе в приложение

```
 private void restartNotify() {
        startService(new Intent(Home.this, MyService.class));}
```

В службе в методе `onCreate` забираются все данные из бд для сверки, `onStartCommand` не работает совсем и не вызывается повторно при скрытии и удалении приложения из стека приложений.
Каждую минуту служба сканирует все данные и отправляет уведомление. Однако все прекрасно работает только до версии андроид 10.0, начиная с андроид 10.0 ни служба ни уведомления в фоновом режиме не работают, несмотря на то что все разрешения установлены. Сначала думал что ошибка какая-то в разрешении на геолокацию, но после длительной проверки было установлено что не работает служба

```
private void fn_getlocation(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable){

        }else {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (isNetworkEnable) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"isNetworkEnable",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    location = null;
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {

                            Log.d("Networklatitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                            Log.d("Networklongitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            fn_update(location);
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (isGPSEnable) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"isGPSEnable",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    location = null;
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            Log.d("GPSlatitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                            Log.d("GPSlongitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            fn_update(location);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //if (!isForeground(MyService.this)) {
                    i++;
                    Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"i = "+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("area", "i = " + i );
                    fn_getlocation();//}
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void fn_update(Location location){
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        latLng = new LatLng(lat,lon);
        for (int i =0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            double lat2 = list.get(i).getLatitude();
            double lon2 = list.get(i).getLongitude();
            Location locationA = new Location("point A");
            locationA.setLatitude(lat2);
            locationA.setLongitude(lon2);
            distance1 = locationA.distanceTo(location);
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"distance1: "+distance1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("area", "area1: " + distance1 + " " + list.get(i).getTime_info());
            if (distance1<100&&list_pos.get(i)==0) {
                Log.d("area","area: send1");
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"notif1 send",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                list_pos.set(i,1);
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, LocateNotification.class);
                intent2.putExtra(MainAdvertModel.class.getCanonicalName(), list.get(i));
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"send Notification",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                sendBroadcast(intent2);
                break;
            }
            else if (list_pos.get(i)==1&&distance1>=500){
                Log.d("area","area: restart1");
                list_pos.set(i,0);
            }
        }
        for (int i =0; i<list_lost.size(); i++) {
            double lat2 = list_lost.get(i).getLatitude();
            double lon2 = list_lost.get(i).getLongitude();
            Location locationA = new Location("point A");
            locationA.setLatitude(lat2);
            locationA.setLongitude(lon2);
            distance2 = locationA.distanceTo(location);
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"distance2: "+distance2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("area", "area2: " + distance2 + " " + list_lost.get(i).getTime_info());
            if (distance2<300&&list_pos2.get(i)==0) {
                Log.d("area","area: send2");
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"notif2 send",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                list_pos2.set(i,1);
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, LostNotification.class);
                intent2.putExtra(LostAdvertModel.class.getCanonicalName(), list.get(i));
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"send Notification",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                sendBroadcast(intent2);
                break;
            }
            else if (list_pos2.get(i)==1&&distance2>=500){
                Log.d("area","area: restart2");
                list_pos2.set(i,0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Служба должна быть foreground, и запуск службы по-другому. И что бы она жила, должен быть создан Notification у службы

Comment: есть какой-нибудь пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведу выдержки из своего проекта, если что забуду, не обессудьте

Манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".MainService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

проверка на повторный запуск службы

```
static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context ctx, Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Запуск службы

```
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(getApplication(), MainService.class)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplication(), new Intent(getApplication(), MainService.class));
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(getApplication(), MainService.class));
            }
        }
```

Сама служба

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel_main;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder_main;
NotificationManager notificationManager;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    // инициализация 
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    _create_notification();
}

public void _create_notification() {
    try {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationChannel_main = new NotificationChannel("ID", "Main", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel_main);
            builder_main = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannel_main.getId())
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setSound(null)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_onesignal_default)
                    .setContentText("");
        } else {
            builder_main = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground(1, builder_main.build());
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: как это можно связать с ресивером?, ведь уведомления у меня отправляются оттуда, в самом сервисе происходит проверка геопозиции

Comment: Создайте ресивер внутри сервиса и шлите или принимайте интенты (Это уже отдельный вопрос). Никаких проблем. Если это решает вашу проблему, отметьте как решение.

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: Может создам новый вопрос, покажете как реализовать?

Comment: Создавайте, не я, так другие ответят